# Kurento Custom Plugin : How to send events to java server asynchronously

Tags: c++, asynchronous, kurento

I am working on Kurento custom plugin, In which I have to make some curl web request and send the audio to a server and wait for server's response. I was wondering is there any way by which we can raise events to java server from kurento custom plugin synchronously. Shall I make asyc calls to raise events or make my curl calls async ?

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit the architecture of the plugin that you want to accomplish? Maybe it's possible what you , but can't tell you with the information you provide. An example or what are you sending to the http server and what you expect to do with it will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Events fired from the media server are asynchronous. Requests, on the other hand, are synchronous, as there is only one thread attending incoming requests.

I would suggest an event-based asynchronous model in all parts, so you don't block your call to your app server. If you still want to do that, you might wrap your asynchronous event in a synchronous call. You might want to have a look at some helper classes that we use for our tests: the [AsyncManager](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-java/blob/b0d0c2f37755560677a3a6c2162c4d95b09418f7/kurento-integration-tests/kurento-client-test/src/test/java/org/kurento/client/test/util/AsyncManager.java) and the [AsyncEventManager](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-java/blob/b0d0c2f37755560677a3a6c2162c4d95b09418f7/kurento-integration-tests/kurento-client-test/src/test/java/org/kurento/client/test/util/AsyncEventManager.java). You can find an example of usage in any of the tests, but maybe [this](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-java/blob/b0d0c2f37755560677a3a6c2162c4d95b09418f7/kurento-integration-tests/kurento-client-test/src/test/java/org/kurento/client/test/PlayerEndpointTest.java#L79) one is closer to what you want to achieve.

Comment: any way to do this in javascript?